# SoftException in Application.cpp:422: Mismatch between target UID (584) and UID (99) of file

Tags: php, linux, centos, suphp

I was setting up the Apache on CentOS server. My first testing script index.php as well as any others was causing:

```
500 Internal Server Error
```

I opened the log file (in my case /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log and /usr/local/apache/logs/suphp_log) and I found some entries as follows:

```
SoftException in Application.cpp:422: Mismatch between target UID (99) and UID (32010) of file "/usr/local/apache/htdocs/{DIRECTORY OF MY PROJECT}/index.php"
```

-AND-

```
[Wed Feb 11 15:16:03 2015] [warn] UID of script "/usr/local/apache/htdocs/{DIRECTORY OF MY PROJECT}/index.php" is smaller than min_uid
```

What I understood my fie permissions and/or ownership was wrong.
Is there any recommended file ownership for website scripts in CentOS environment?

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 11):

The easiest solution I found was by using a command line:

```
chown -R 99:99 {PROJECT ROOT DIRECTORY}
```

where 99 is the **target UID** value required by the server.

Alternatively you may use WinSCP. Just right click on the project root directory, select permissions  and enter in Group and Owner fields value 99 (the same as **target UID** from error log), also check box '*Set group, owner and permissions recursively*', click OK and after a while the files and folders ownership should adjusted to the one that is required by the server.

Comment: Thanks this fix my problem.